# Is it possible to install mod_ruid2 in Amazon Linux2

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, lamp

Im using **mod_ruid2** in **Amazon Linux 1** with **LAMP** and since AWS has removed it I'm trying to install mod_ruid2 in **Amazon Linux 2** for LAMP but I cannot able to install it so can anyone guide me how to do it or is there any other modules which is similar to this in AWS Linux 2